# How can i make this object pattern work?

Tags: javascript, module, iife

This pattern really floats my boat but how can i make it act as a base class without using 'new', 'this' nor 'Object.create()'? Is it possible?

```
var myObj = (function () {

    var x = 0;
    var privFunc = function() { console.log(x); };

    // interface
    return { 
        init    : function (arg) { x=arg; },
        getVal  : privFunc
    };

}());

var abc = myObj;
abc.init(123);
abc.getVal(); //123

var xyz = myObj;
xyz.init(456);
xyz.getVal(); //456

abc.getVal(); //456? want it to return 123
```

Comment: If you want it to return `123`, then don't change its value in the `init` function. However, then there's no point to the pattern at all unless you have other use for `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a single object, and then you just copy the reference to it. If you want separate objects you need to call the function once for each object:

```
function myObj() {

    var x = 0;
    var privFunc = function() { console.log(x); };

    // interface
    return { 
        init    : function (arg) { x=arg; },
        getVal  : privFunc
    };

}

var abc = myObj();
abc.init(123);
abc.getVal(); //123

var xyz = myObj();
xyz.init(456);
xyz.getVal(); //456

abc.getVal(); //123
```

Comment: Thanks so much; further reading, it seems I'm creating a factory function which is much easier for me to use. I'm not too keen on 'this' and 'new' keywords and want to write my modules as objects. I'm trying to decide on a consistent pattern before I start a large project - 'tis confusing stuff.